# When starting gparted "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Tags: partitioning, gparted

This is exactly my problem. running ubuntu server 12.04. sorry I couldn't find a way to mark the thread "unanswered".

[Resize a 2TB partition on a 3TB disk created with fdisk](https://askubuntu.com/q/172930/190460)

I downloaded and installed gparted - however I get an errors when trying to run it. can you guys help me? my terminal output is below:

```
keysersoze@the-usual-suspects:/$ sudo gparted /dev/sda

(gpartedbin:18064): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
keysersoze@the-usual-suspects:/$
```

note that I am fairly new to linux. thanks for your patience.

Comment: gparted is a gui, so you should be launching it from command line with gksudo or gksu. But if you have 2TB that is MBR(msdos) you may need to convert to gpt(GUID). You can use gdisk for conversion as well as setting up partitions.

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is to use an Xserver on another machine to display the GUI elements you can't see on a server.  Set the environment variable to the local machine running the Xserver.  Where this is an IP address and the screen # on the X server.

```
export DISPLAY="192.168.1.5:0"
```

then run :

```
sudo gparted
```

With another Ubuntu machine you will need to change firewall rules to allow this.  Using windows you can do this with MobaXterm which runs a local X server.

Comment: It didn't work for me. `(gpartedbin:16598): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 192.168.1.200:0`

Answer (score 3):

### Continue on your own risk

*(Please, go to the next section if you want a more secure method to resize ext* partitions)

The tool you are looking for is `parted` which is the backend for gparted, also you must make sure that **your partition table is GPT**, if it's MBR it won't support partitions bigger than 2TB.

This method is only for non-mounted partitions, so you might like to do a backup too if something go wire.

- First open `parted`

  ```
  braiam@bt:~$ sudo parted
  [sudo] password for braiam: 
  GNU Parted 2.3
  Using /dev/sda
  Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
  (parted)
  ```
- Now that you are here, you must make sure what driver you want to modify. As you see, I'm using `sda`, if what you want is use `sdb` or `sd-something` you must use `select`:

  ```
  (parted) select                                                           
  New device?  [/dev/sda]? /dev/sd                                          
  sda   sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sda6  sda7  sda8  sdb   sdc   sdd   sde   sdf   sdf1  sdf2  
  New device?  [/dev/sda]? /dev/sdf
  Using /dev/sdf
  (parted)
  ```
- List all the partitions with `print /dev/sdf`:

  ```
  (parted) print /dev/sdf
  Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sdf: 8040MB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos

  Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
   1      32.8kB  2418MB  2418MB  primary               boot, hidden
   2      2418MB  8039MB  5621MB  primary  ntfs
  ```

  Let assume that my NTFS partition is empty for now. Now I want to grow partition number one (notice that my partition table says `msdos` in your case it should say `gpt`).
- Now comes the truth hour. Using `resize` we must set the partition number one to use all the disk, how we do this?

  > resize NUMBER START END                  resize partition NUMBER and its file system

  Hence, number should be `1`, start should be the same `32.8kB` and the end should be `8039MB` (remember that you should change the numbers, since I don't have a >1TB drive).

  ```
  resize 1 32.8kB 8039MB
  WARNING: you are attempting to use parted to operate on (resize) a file system.
  parted's file system manipulation code is not as robust as what you'll find in
  dedicated, file-system-specific packages like e2fsprogs.  We recommend
  you use parted only to manipulate partition tables, whenever possible.
  Support for performing most operations on most types of file systems
  will be removed in an upcoming release.
  ```

Nice warning, continue reading.

---

### The recommended method? e2fsprogs? but I don't have that!

Seems that the message is quite old, and `e2fsprogs` is not called like that anymore (the package keep its name, through), but `resize2fs`. This program is capable of resize any ext2/3/4 filesystem. Cool! Now how I do it? Simple:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdf1 8039M
```

(Remember that the size is the current size + the size you want to add)

Here you could use M for Megabytes, G for Gigabytes. You should also verify for errors:

```
sudo e2fsck -f -p /dev/sdf1
```

Done.

Comment: The resize command will fail because as the warning says, parted's filesystem manipulation code is old and broken.  You also don't want to specify a size to `resize2fs` and let it assume the maximum available.

Comment: @psusi I'm not letting resize2fs assume maximum available because OP wants a specific size, also, **I'm in no way recommending parted over other tool**, as it says at the beginning "Please, go to the next section if you want a more secure method to resize ext partitions". I'm only telling him that `parted` is not the way to go and why.

Comment: You can't resize the filesystem until after you have resized the partition holding it.  Trying `resize2fs` and specifying the size without first enlarging the partition will just throw an error saying it isn't large enough.  Once you have changed the size of the partition, it is best to omit the size to `resize2fs` so it will automatically fill the whole partition.

Answer (score 0):

`gparted` is a graphical application for managing partitions.

The error you see above is because `gparted` is trying to open a graphical console, but since this is Ubuntu server there is no graphical display.

Some options:

You can use command line partitioning tools such as `fdisk` or `sfdisk`. These are harder to drive, so read the manual carefully.

Alternately, if you have another machine running ubuntu desktop, you can use `ssh -X` from that machine to the server to log in with X11 forwarding. In that shell you can run `gparted` and it should display on the desktop machine - although you will probably have to tweak the `ssh` configs a bit and install some X11 programs on the server to get it all working.

Comment: You will need to use `parted` since `fdisk` and `sfdisk` don't understand GPT, which is needed on disks > 2 TB.

Comment: Is that still that case? I used fdisk and sfdisk to partition two 3TB disks on Monday and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Yep.. if you did that then you're only using 2TB of the disk.  Or technically I think you can make a 1TB partition then a second one that starts at 1TB and is 2TB long.

Comment: Ok, so the single partition on the drive is 2TB. Why does pvdisplay say the partition is 2.73 TB? Why does vgdisplay reckon I have over 2.5TB allocated to volumes?

Comment: Just repartitioned the disk as GPT with gparted - ended up with exactly the same amount of space.

Comment: The other way the msdos partition table can exceed 2TiB disks is if the logical sector size is > 512 bytes.  Does parted show the logical sector size is 4k?  Most drives use 512 byte logical sectors for compatibility.

Comment: Yes, the disk is using a 4k block size.

Comment: `cfdisk` also works quite well in a CLI environment

Answer (score 0):

As David pointed out, `gparted` is a gui application, so you won't be able to use it on a server without a gui.  You will need to use `parted` to manipulate partitions on the command line.  It can not directly resize partitions however.  Instead you will have to delete the existing partition and recreate it with the exact same start position, but a longer length, and then run another tool to resize the filesystem inside the partition.

First you need to put it into sector mode with the `unit s` command and `print` the existing table.  Use `rm 1` to remove the partition, then `mkpart` to create a new one.  Specify the same starting sector it had before, then specify the end.  You can do that in a form like "+2500G" for 2,500 GB from the start rather than having to specify the exact sector.  `quit` when done, then run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`.  This is assuming the partition is number 1 on the first disk in the system.

If the partition is mounted at the time, then in 12.04 you will get an error trying to change it with `parted` and will have to reboot for the change to take effect before using `resize2fs`.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple, put this commands in console:

```
sudo touch .Xauthority  
sudo xauth merge ~name_of_user/.Xauthority  
export DISPLAY=:0.0  
sudo gparted
```

*change name_of_user to your login user

Comment: sudo touch .Xauthority
sudo xauth merge ~name_of_user/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0.0

Answer (score 0):

I was having same trouble. The error message said I was in trouble because of some 'MIT-Magic-Cookie-1'. None of the above advice helped, but I figured out it was all about root, server and desktop complications, because I had an upgrade from zesty to artful before. Some packages were removed of course.

Here is what solved my problem:

1. Create user root.
2. Login as user root, ...this worked out for me pressing the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F2
3. From the terminal simply: `startx`
4. Super key and look for GParted.

I believe this is an ideal solution to switch between the X-server and wayland/mir. If you want to return back to your previous account, logout from X Window and terminal, press Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

Running GParted as a normal user instead of root would prevent the following:

```
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
(gpartedbin:3232): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:46:48.189: cannot open display:
```